# How to implement a Decorator with non-local equality?

Tags: python, decorator, multiple-inheritance

Greetings, currently I am refactoring one of my programs, and I found an interesting problem.

I have Transitions in an automata. Transitions always have a start-state and an end-state. Some Transitions have a label, which encodes a certain Action that must be performed upon traversal. No label means no action. Some transitions have a condition, which must be fulfilled in order to traverse this condition, if there is no condition, the transition is basically an epsilon-transition in an NFA and will be traversed without consuming an input symbol.

I need the following operations:

- check if the transition has a label
- get this label
- add a label to a transition
- check if the transition has a condition
- get this condition
- check for equality

Judging from the first five points, this sounds like a clear decorator, with a base transition and two decorators: Labeled and Condition. However, this approach has a problem: two transitions are considered equal if their start-state and end-state are the same, the labels at both transitions are equal (or not-existing) and both conditions are the same (or not existing). With a decorator, I might have two transitions Labeled("foo", Conditional("bar", Transition("baz", "qux"))) and Conditional("bar", Labeled("foo", Transition("baz", "qux"))) which need a non-local equality, that is, the decorators would need to collect all the data and the Transition must compare this collected data on a set-base:

```
class Transition(object):
    def __init__(self, start, end):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
    def get_label(self):
        return None
    def has_label(self):
        return False
    def collect_decorations(self, decorations):
        return decorations
    def internal_equality(self, my_decorations, other):
        try:
            return (self.start == other.start
                    and self.end == other.end
                    and my_decorations = other.collect_decorations())
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.internal_equality(self.collect_decorations({}), other)

class Labeled(object):
    def __init__(self, label, base):
        self.base = base
        self.label = label
    def has_label(self):
        return True
    def get_label(self):
        return self.label
    def collect_decorations(self, decorations):
        assert 'label' not in decorations
        decorations['label'] = self.label
        return self.base.collect_decorations(decorations)
    def __getattr__(self, attribute):
        return self.base.__getattr(attribute)
```

Is this a clean approach? Am I missing something?

I am mostly confused, because I can solve this - with longer class names - using cooperative multiple inheritance:

```
class Transition(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # init is pythons MI-madness ;-)
        super(Transition, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.start = kwargs['start']
        self.end = kwargs['end']
    def get_label(self):
        return None
    def get_condition(self):
        return None
    def __eq__(self, other):
        try:
            return self.start == other.start and self.end == other.end
        except AttributeError:
            return False

class LabeledTransition(Transition):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LabeledTransition).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.label = kwargs['label']
    def get_label(self):
        return self.label
    def __eq__(self):
        super_result = super(LabeledTransition, self).__eq__(other)
        try:
            return super_result and self.label == other.label
        except AttributeError:
            return False

class ConditionalTransition(Transition):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ConditionalTransition, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.condition = kwargs['condition']

    def get_condition(self):
        return self.condition

    def __eq__(self, other):
        super_result = super(ConditionalTransition, self).__eq__(other)
        try:
            return super_result and self.condition = other.condition
        except AttributeError:
            return False

# ConditionalTransition about the same, with get_condition
class LabeledConditionalTransition(LabeledTransition, ConditionalTransition):
    pass
```

the class LabledConditionalTransition behaves exactly as expected - and having no code in there is appealing and I do not thing MI is confusing at this size.

Of course, the third option would be to just hammer everything into a single transition class with a bunch of in has_label/has_transition.

So... I am confused. Am I missing something? Which implementation looks better? How do you handle similar cases, that is, objects which look like a Decorator could handle them, but then, such a non-local method comes around?

*EDIT*:
Added the ConditionalTransition-class. Basically, this kinda behaves like the decorator, minus the order created by the order of creating the decorators, the transition checks for start and end being correct, the LabeledTransition-class checks for label being correct and ConditionalTransition checks for condition being correct.

Comment: looks to me like you are trying to write java code in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its clear that nobody really understands your question. I would suggest putting it in context and making it shorter. As an example, here's one possible implementation of the state pattern in python, please study it to get an idea.

```
class State(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

class Automaton(object):
    def __init__(self, instance, start):
        self._state = start
        self.transitions = instance.transitions()

    def get_state(self):
        return self._state

    def set_state(self, target):
        transition = self.transitions.get((self.state, target))
        if transition:
            action, condition = transition
            if condition:
                if condition():
                    if action:
                        action()
                    self._state = target
            else:
                self._state = target
        else:
            self._state = target

    state = property(get_state, set_state)

class Door(object):
    open = State('open')
    closed = State('closed')

    def __init__(self, blocked=False):
        self.blocked = blocked

    def close(self):
        print 'closing door'

    def do_open(self):
        print 'opening door'

    def not_blocked(self):
        return not self.blocked

    def transitions(self):
        return {
            (self.open, self.closed):(self.close, self.not_blocked),
            (self.closed, self.open):(self.do_open, self.not_blocked),
        }

if __name__ == '__main__':
    door = Door()
    automaton = Automaton(door, door.open)

    print 'door is', automaton.state
    automaton.state = door.closed
    print 'door is', automaton.state
    automaton.state = door.open
    print 'door is', automaton.state
    door.blocked = True
    automaton.state = door.closed
    print 'door is', automaton.state
```

the output of this programm would be:

```
door is open
closing door
door is closed
opening door
door is open
door is open
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code that was posted, the only difference between Transition and Labeled Transition is the return of get_lable() and has_label().  In which case you can compress these two a single class that sets a label attribute to None and

```
return self.label is not None
```

in the has_label() function.

Can you post the code for the `ConditionalTransition` class?  I think this would make it clearer.